# pipenv Post-Install Actions

Tags: python, pipenv, pharo, gtoolkit

I'm using Python via Pharo/GToolkit's [PythonBridge](https://github.com/feenkcom/PythonBridge), which uses pipenv under the hood.

Things are kicked off via this built-in PythonBridge script (`install_env.sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
pipenv install
pipenv run pip install debugpy
```

One of the dependencies in my Pipfile is [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python). [Its docs list two main steps to installation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro#pip):

```sh
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

My question is: where do I "put" the second `playwright install` command?

It doesn't seem practical to alter `install_env.sh`, which is generated at some point by PythonBridge. I was hoping pipenv might have a concept of a "post-install script hook", but DuckDuckGo-ing various combinations of those words, as well as reading [the pipenv docs](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) didn't reveal anything seemingly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this feature is not supported now, you can put your needs here https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2817 in order to try the pipenv develop that feature.

Comment: Thanks, I added my use case as [a comment](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2817#issuecomment-1195697265)

Answer (score 1):

[Until it's actually supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71769713/72321), a workaround is to use scripts in your Pipfile:

```
[scripts]
hooks = "playwright install"
```

And run `pipenv install && pipenv run hooks`.

Example with multiple hooks:

```
[scripts]
hooks = "bash -c 'pipenv run hook_1 && pipenv run hook_2'"
hook_1 = "some_command"
hook_2 = "another_command"
```